# Reading numbers from txt in C++ (keep same # of decimals)

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point

I have a txt with numbers in this format:

```
256.6 689.8
460.9 127.2
1027.5 110.5
1516.1 92.6
1319.9 580.3
```

And the following code in C++ to read them:

```
Vector<float> txt_data;
fstream myfile(path_to_file, ios_base::in);                
while (myfile >> num){
    txt_data.push_back(num);
}
myfile.close();
```

All fine here. Then, I want to copy those coordinates into a *openCV Mat* variable. For doing so I first:

```
Mat temp;
temp_ = Mat(txt_data.size()/2,2,CV_32F,&txt_data.front());
```

When showing the resulting matrix I get this:

```
[256.60001, 689.79999;
460.89999, 127.2;
1027.5, 110.5;
1516.1, 92.599998;
1319.9, 580.29999]
```

In the next step of the algorithm I have to add a displacement vector to each point. I can do that by just summing each column in the matrix by a integer *disp_vector = [dx,dy]*. However sometimes (and this is the weird thing) it works ok, some other, it doesn't and gives other numbers (weird things like: 1320+12 = 1224). Any idea how can I correctly obtain the data from the file with just one decimal for all values?

I've tried to do something like:

```
float clean_one_dec = floor(all_decimals_float * 10) / 10);
```

But I get the same value.

**EDIT:** I just found the error to my problem. All this code is inside a function which accepts the displacement vector as an input variable. The vector is defined as:

```
Vect<float> d_vec;
```

and has only two values: *dx* and *dy*.

It turns out that (and I don't know why) when performing the sum to one of the coordinates, *dx* and/or *dy* become 0. (Weird ,right?). I just created another variable and copied the input *d_vec* there. It's working now fine.

Comment: [FYI] `&txt_data.front()` is that same as `txt_data.data()`

Comment: Are you aware that a value like `256.6` (along with most of your input values) is not exactly representable as a `float`? Assuming that `float` is IEEE 754 binary32 format (which is extremely likely, but not guaranteed), when you read the decimal text value from the file, it'll (probably) be rounded to the nearest number which *is* exactly representable as a float, namely `256.600006103515625`. And when you print the matrix, it's just showing you that value, rounded to a suitable number of places for output. Storing `256.6` exactly in a `float` simply isn't possible.

Comment: I didn't know. Thank you for the info.

Comment: Then you should totally read this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)